# POSTing Vue form elements into a Rails 5.1 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, strong-parameters

I am trying to post a number of checked items into a Rails controller, but cannot seem to get it working properly.

In my form I have:

```
<%= form_for(listing, html: { id: listing.id, class: 'listing_form' }) do |f| %>
  ...

  <div v-for="(item, idx) in items">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" v-model="checkedItems[idx]" :value="item.id">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description">{{ item.text }}</span>
    </label>
  </div>

  ...

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-success', 'v-on:click.prevent': 'submitListing' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and my Vue code looks like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('listing-multistep') != null) {
  Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('input[name="authenticity_token"]').getAttribute('value');
  var listingForm = document.getElementsByClassName('listing_form')[0];
  var id = listingForm.dataset.id;

  const listingForm = new Vue({
    el: '#listing-multistep',
    data: {
      id: id,
      name: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      address: '',
      items: [
          {id: 0, text: "Item1"},
          {id: 1, text: "Item2"},
          {id: 2, text: "Item3"}
      ],
      checkedItems: []
    },
    methods: {
      submitListing: function() {
        var itemNames = []
        var checkedIndices = []

        // Probably a better way to do this...
        // Get the indices of all checkedItems that are true
        this.checkedItems.forEach((elt, idx) => {
          if(elt === true){ checkedIndices.push(idx) }
        });
        // Get the value of all the above indices    
        this.items.map((item) => {
          if(checkedIndices.includes(item.id)){
            itemNames.push(item.text);
          }
        });

        var listingObj = {
          id: this.id,
          name: this.name,
          city: this.city,
          state: this.state,
          address: this.address,
          items: itemNames  // <--- this is an array of items which isn't filtering through to Rails in the POST request
        }

        if(this.id == null) {
          console.log(listingObj)
          // POST the listingObj if it's a new listing
          this.$http.post('/listings', {listing: listingObj}).then(
            response => {
              window.location = `/listings/${response.body.id}`
          }, response => {
            console.log(response)
          })
        } else {
          // PUT the listingObj if it's an existing listing
          this.$http.put(`/listings/${this.id}`, {listing: listingObj}).then(
            response => {
              window.location = `/listings/${response.body.id}`
          }, response => {
            console.log(response)
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

While most of the data is being sent across and the listing is being generated, the problem is that the `items` array does not get to the Rails controller.

My database is PostgreSQL and the items filed in the database is defined as follows in `schema.rb` (so an array field should be possible):

```
t.text "items", default: [], array: true
```

I am allowing it to pass through the strong params in my controller:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  private
  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(
      :name,
      :city,
      :state,
      :address,
      :items)
  end
end
```

but cannot figure out why the listingOb's `items` field isn't being carried across to Rails. Any idea why this may be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. The strong params in Rails to permit an array field looks like this:

```
def listing_params
  params.require(:listing).permit(
    :name,
    :city,
    :state,
    :address,
    :items => []
  )
end
```

works now!